# How can I use setState(array) inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I want to make this process

1. declare `[reviewList, setReviewList] = useState<any>(null)`
2. If `reviewList === null` JSX will show `<div>Loading</div>`
3. If `reviewList !== null` JSX will show list information

So, I wrote code like this.

1. First I declare variable use by useState() and declare list which assign in reviewList

```js
let [reviewList, setReviewList] = useState<any>(null);
let list = [
  {
    photo : "assets/likelist1.png",
    name : "Island one",
    info : "300m · California",
    rating : "4.5(37)"
  },
  {
    photo : "assets/likelist2.png",
    name : "Island two",
    info : "300m · Maxico",
    rating : "4.3(300)"
  },
  {
    photo : "assets/likelist3.png",
    name : "Island three",
    info : "150m · Maxico",
    rating : "4.3(00)"
  },
  {
    photo : "assets/likelist1.png",
    name : "Island four",
    info : "300m · Dubai",
    rating : "4.5(11)"
  },
  {
    photo : "assets/likelist1.png",
    name : "Island five",
    info : "300m · Japan",
    rating : "3.9(01)"
  }
]
```

2. JSX show conditional rendering according to value of `reviewList`

```js
<div className={styles.reviewListBox}>
        {
          reviewList === null  
          ?
          <div>Loading</div>
          :
          reviewList.map((el : any)=>{
            <div className={styles.reviewEach}>
              <img className={styles.reviewEachImage} src={el.photo}/>
              <div className={styles.reivewTextBox}>
                <div className={styles.reviewNameAndRating}>
                  <span>{el.name}</span>
                  <img className={styles.reviewRatingStar} src="assets/star.png"/>
                  <span className={styles.reviewEachRating} >{el.rating}</span>
                </div>
                <span className={styles.reviewEachInfo}>{el.info}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          })
        }
</div>
```

3. and I change state in useEffect (I understand useEffect function works after rendering so, I expect that I can see loading text, before setState function, and after that I will see list)

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("First : ", reviewList);
    async function getListFunc() {
      let asyncFunc = await getListInfo();
    }
    getListFunc();
    console.log("Second : ",reviewList);
  },[])

  let getListInfo = async () => {
    console.log("First-Async : ",reviewList);
    let result = await setReviewList(list);
    console.log("Second-Async",reviewList);
  }
```

but when I run this code, I can't see list.
Maybe, re-rendering doesn't work. I learned when state is changed, react redering again. in this situation what is the solution also, Is my understanding of rendering correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `async/await` because `list` is static.

You also need to pass [`key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to `<div className={styles.reviewEach} key={el.name}>` which helps to identify your components.

`setReviewList` does not return any `result` as you expected, and `reviewList` state will be updated asynchronously, so you cannot see state update in `console.log("Second : ",reviewList);` as well.

```js
//change it to `import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'` in yourcode
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const styles = {} //fake styles

const MyComponent = () => {
  let [reviewList, setReviewList] = useState(null);
  let list = [
    {
      photo: "assets/likelist1.png",
      name: "Island one",
      info: "300m · California",
      rating: "4.5(37)",
    },
    {
      photo: "assets/likelist2.png",
      name: "Island two",
      info: "300m · Maxico",
      rating: "4.3(300)",
    },
    {
      photo: "assets/likelist3.png",
      name: "Island three",
      info: "150m · Maxico",
      rating: "4.3(00)",
    },
    {
      photo: "assets/likelist1.png",
      name: "Island four",
      info: "300m · Dubai",
      rating: "4.5(11)",
    },
    {
      photo: "assets/likelist1.png",
      name: "Island five",
      info: "300m · Japan",
      rating: "3.9(01)",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const getListInfo = () => {
      setReviewList(list);
    };
    getListInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.reviewListBox}>
      {!reviewList ? (
        <div>Loading</div>
      ) : (
        reviewList.map((el) => (
          <div className={styles.reviewEach} key={el.name}>
            <img className={styles.reviewEachImage} src={el.photo} />
            <div className={styles.reivewTextBox}>
              <div className={styles.reviewNameAndRating}>
                <span>{el.name}</span>
                <img
                  className={styles.reviewRatingStar}
                  src="assets/star.png"
                />
                <span className={styles.reviewEachRating}>{el.rating}</span>
              </div>
              <span className={styles.reviewEachInfo}>{el.info}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you use async and await but if you want to show updated list you can add dependency in you useEffect like this hope this will work:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("First : ", reviewList);
    async function getListFunc() {
      let asyncFunc = await getListInfo();
    }
    getListFunc();
    console.log("Second : ",reviewList);
  },[getListInfo])

  let getListInfo = async () => {
    console.log("First-Async : ",reviewList);
    let result = await setReviewList(list);
    console.log("Second-Async",reviewList);
  }
```